# Gradle fails to sync in android studio 0.8.8

Tags: gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have just updated my android studio to version 0.8.8 and finally managed to put map box sdk in it and its working perfectly. I wanted to add another libraries which is my case universal image loader and Facebook sdk when i try to add one of them gradle project sync fails basic functionality
will not work error shows up.
How can this be solved.
Thank you.

Comment: I have the same problem. Restarting Android Studio does successfully sync the project from gradle (at least for me). I tried cleaning all gradle caches without solving the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

6 hours ago Android Studio 0.8.9 was released fixing this problem:

http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio089released

This solved the problem for me, and will most likely do the same for you! The update is currently on Canary channel so you probably have to activate it in your update settings.

Regards,
David